# scrollTo triggers mouseover asynchronously

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseover

While using jQuery's `element.scrollTop()` on a fixed dimensions element, a `mouseover` event is triggered on that elements children, but not directly. Instead, the `mouseover` event occurs ~110ms (Chrome 11, OS X) or ~15ms (Firefox 4, OS X) after the `scrollTop()` method has been called.

When the client presses a key (down arrow), my script calls the `scrollTop()` method to scroll the div. The `mouseover` event handler then interferes with the keyboard event, which is an unwanted behavior. The problem is, since the event occurs asynchronously, there is no way for me to determine whether the mouse has really been moved or not.

How do I suppress the effects of that `mouseover` event? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: I fixed it by using a mousemove handler and a boolean flag, since mousemove is called after mouseover. However, it feels like a dirty fix plus it relies on that the mousemove event is called, but it works.

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce it. Is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/jtyEV/?

Comment: No, I mean like http://jsfiddle.net/jtyEV/1/

Comment: Could you not take the mouse cursor coordinates at keydown, and compare when the scrollTop is complete?

Answer (score 0):

I like [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

> It works like (and was derived from) jQuery's built-in hover. However, instead of immediately calling the onMouseOver function, it waits until the user's mouse slows down enough before making the call.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems to serve a good purpose although in my script it will not be optimal.